# Qt Cmake error compilation "GuiSupportQt not found"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, user-interface, cmake

I'm new to Qt and i already have a problem so i start to create a simple UI for my VTK project, first of all, i tested a sample project UI designed by Qt in Qt 5.5.0 and compiled in Cmake 3.10 and VS2013 programmed with C++, and i've got a line after compiling with Cmake before "Configuration done" saying that"GuiSupportQt not found." i ignored it and generated solution then i gone to VS2013 to compile the solution provided by Cmake , i didn't find my project after opening solution in VS2013, i found only the common 2 projects that are named ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK.

For more info, i've compiled before a non Gui project (3d vtk visualisation with vtk rendered without Qt) which is my own homework project and i've got a successful results which means in my opinion that the problem appears exactly when i compile a project that uses Qt considering that my Qt-VTK are compiled before with Cmake and built with VS2013 without any errors.

This is the code of Qt project sample that i used to test :
https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Qt/RenderWindowUISingleInheritance

This is what i get when i try to compile it with Cmake :

`The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.21005.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.21005.1
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
VTK_VERSION: 7.1.1
GuiSupportQt not found.
Configuring done
Generating done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking a while i found out another tricky solution to evade problems since i had Vtk visualisation part work fine and i work on windows, so i just sent parameters via command in cmd using Qt gui and then Vtk project compiled exe file will take parameters in execution (iso-value,data folder name..ect) in argv[] array then launch it in a new window, so i didn't have to compile Qt project with Cmake.